# How to find the linearization of this function($ x^4+y^3-x^3-y^2+x^2+y-2=0$)?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, linear-approximation, linearization

This past paper question about linearization for my calculus 1 course has been bothering me. I spent 5 days trying to solve it.

Considering the equation:
$ x^4+y^3-x^3-y^2+x^2+y-2=0$

We accept and can use without justification the fact that, for each number x, there is a
unique number $f(x)$ such that $x^4+f(x)^3-x^3-f(x)^2+x^2+f(x)-2=0$ and that the
function $f$ defined in this manner is differentiable everywhere.

a) Find the linearization of $f$ at 1. (Justify your answer.)

b) Use the linearization from a) to propose an approximate value for $f(1.001)$.

Comment: Try to ask only 1 question at a time, and show what you have tried. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $x=1$ gives
$$ y^3-y^2+y-1=0 \text{ or }(y-1)(y^2+1)=0. $$
So $y=1$ or $f(1)=1$. Differentiating
$$ x^4+f^3(x)-x^3-f^2(x)+x^2+f(x)-2=0 $$
gives
$$ 4x^3+3f^2(x)f'(x)-3x^2-2f(x)f'(x)+2x+f'(x)=0. $$
Letting $x=1$, one has
$$ f'(1)=-\frac32. $$
Thus
$$ f(x)=f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)+O((x-1)^2). $$
Using this, it is easy to obtain $f(1.001)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what is O for in the equation :- $f(x)=f(1)+f′(1)(x−1)+O((x−1)^2)$ .

Comment: A function $f$ is said to be $O(x^2)$ if $|f(x)|\le kx^2$ for some constant $k$.